# OAuth2 without secret

Tags: oauth

I'm trying to build a **OAuth2 provider** that won't need any *secret token* or *url_redirect* whitelist.

Here's the idea:

- You copy paste the button on your website
- **Provider (us)** authenticates **user**, gives him a **auth token** linked to **HTTP_REFERER** in our database (using window.postMessage to send the token back to the parent window).
- **Site** asks user infos from **Provider (us)** with **referer_origin** as a parameter.

That way, we are sure that tokens will always stay on the same domain. No need for secret keys. Is there a flaw in my schema?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using *implicit flow*, your scheme has no drawbacks: `client_secret` makes no sense for implicit flow anyway.

In case of *authorization code flow*, `client_secret` serves one additional purpose which is not covered by your scheme: It prevents desktop applications from impersonating other applications. Within a browser, your scheme will work because browser enforces URL check (within postMessage, or via redirect), but it is possible to build a desktop application or a shell-script, which pretends to be client_id=x, gets the authorization code and then exchanges it to access token. `client_secret` prevents this.

Also note that displaying login screen within an iframe is also a security issue: Other applications may impersonate your iframe and capture user credentials without user noticing that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got the desktop flaw part, but I didn't get the iframe part. Are you referring to phishing issues? I plan not to use iframe anyway, but a popup window.

Comment: Yes, it is about fishing. In case of pop-up, this does not apply because user can see the URL of the pop-up.

Comment: a couple comments, 3.5 yrs later.  A. Implicit flow is now dis-recommended. https://medium.com/oauth-2/why-you-should-stop-using-the-oauth-implicit-grant-2436ced1c926   B. client_secret is not actually a secret in a native app, if the secret is statically embedded into the app itself. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6819#section-5.3.1 .  And therefore the presence of the client_secret so embedded would not prevent "client impersonation".